# Why did Clifford Algebra suddenly gain a resurgence under the name of Geometric Algebra in recent years?

Tags: linear-algebra

To my understanding, this new Geometric algebra thing is actually nothing more than years old [Clifford Algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra). Yet it is advertised by many of its proponents as a fundamentally new thing; why is that?

Comment: Some history here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra  **The term "geometric algebra" was repopularized in the 1960s by Hestenes, who advocated its importance to relativistic physics.**

Comment: Among professional mathematicians, there was no change.

Comment: It is a "fringe" (but valid) approach also in theoretical physics. For some time, though, there was a Geometric Algebra Group at Cambridge University. Some useful material can be found [here](https://www.mrao.cam.ac.uk/~anthony/recent_ga.php).